# Binding Image from FilePicker and project folder in ViewModel

Tags: c#, image, xaml, uwp

I had a problem with displaying image that comes from 2 sources. I have a MainPage and MainPageViewModel. At first time when page loaded we get image from project folder using its Path. 
So in MainPage.xaml

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageUri}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="300" Height="300"/>
```

And MainPageViewModel

```
private string _imageUri;
public RelayCommand PickPhotoCommand { get; set; }
public string ImageUri
{
    get { return _imageUri; }
    set
    {
        _imageUri = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("ImageUri");
    }
}
```

Everything is clear and simple. But then User can pick image from filePicker and old image must be replaced with picked image. But we can't get Uri from StorageFile, that was returned by FilePicker and only option is get BitmapImage from StorageFile using `SetSourceAsync()`. I have two solutions that resolve my problem with displaying image on my xaml page. 
Thi first is - use BitmapImage for both sources, so for image from Project folder or somewhere else I can use

```
 ImageUri = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png"));
```

and change my ImageUri property type to BitmapImage. But my teamlead says that`s not good solution, cause BitmapImage used to change image(Scale, Crop etc.). So it is semantically incorrect.
The second solution is - get file from FilePicker, copy it in Temprorary Folder and then get copiedFile from Folder and take it's path.

```
StorageFile file = await openPicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
StorageFolder tempFolder = ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder;
StorageFile copiedFile = await file.CopyAsync(tempFolder, file.Name, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
var fileFromTemp = await ApplicationData.Current.TemporaryFolder.GetFileAsync(copiedFile.Name);
ImageUri = fileFromTemp.Path;
```

And we can use string for our `ImageUri` property. 
Please give your feedback, which one of this solutions is best and more correct?

Comment: "BitmapImage used to change image (Scale, Crop etc.)", what exactly does that mean? Your team lead probably doesn't know what he's talking about. BitmapImage is the correct approach here. Copying image files to a temporary location is plain nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the type of your view model property to `ImageSource`, i.e. the type of the Image control's `Source` property.

```
private ImageSource image;
public ImageSource Image
{
    get { return image; }
    set
    {
        image = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Image");
    }
}
```

Now you can easily assign a `BitmapImage` e.g.

```
viewModel.Image = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/StoreLogo.png"));
```

or

```
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
using (var stream = await file.OpenReadAsync())
{
    await bitmap.SetSourceAsync(stream);
}
viewModel.Image = bitmap;
```

but also instances of other derived types, like `WriteableBitmap`.

Comment: How I will bind it to my Image control on page? And what difference between your solution and my, where I use the property with BitmapImage type

Comment: You'll bind it as you already did: `<Image Source="{Binding Image}"/>`. The difference is that `ImageSource` is a base class of `BitmapImage`, which provides greater flexibility regarding to which concrete derived type you pass.